# JFormattedTextField doesn't set the value when amount entered and Turkish Lira "TL" icon missing

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

Here is my class to for to display Turkish Lira amount in a correct manner  , my class doesn't set the amount entered for example if i enter 1200 it should be 1,200 TL , do I miss step here ? Should I add action performed event or key released event ?

```
public class TurkisliraFormatterDemo extends JPanel
        implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private double amount = 100000;
    private JFormattedTextField amountField;

    private NumberFormat amountDisplayFormat;
    private NumberFormat amountEditFormat;

    public TurkisliraFormatterDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        setUpFormats();

        amountField = new JFormattedTextField(
                new DefaultFormatterFactory(
                        new NumberFormatter(amountDisplayFormat),
                        new NumberFormatter(amountDisplayFormat),
                        new NumberFormatter(amountEditFormat)));
        amountField.setValue(new Double(amount));
        amountField.setColumns(10);
        amountField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);

        JPanel fieldPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        fieldPane.add(amountField);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

        add(fieldPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == amountField) {
            amount = ((Number) amountField.getValue()).doubleValue();
            amountField.setValue(amount);
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FormatDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new TurkisliraFormatterDemo());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UIManager.put("windows", Boolean.FALSE);
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpFormats() {
        amountDisplayFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("tr", "TR"));
        amountDisplayFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        amountEditFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field won't be formatted while it has focus, trying adding another component to the UI and tabbing focus to it.

This means that while in "edit" mode, it will use the editor formatter, but will use the display formatter when it's not

[image: Field]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class TurkisliraFormatterDemo extends JPanel
                implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private double amount = 100000;
    private JFormattedTextField amountField;

    private NumberFormat amountDisplayFormat;
    private NumberFormat amountEditFormat;

    public TurkisliraFormatterDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        setUpFormats();

        amountField = new JFormattedTextField(
                        new DefaultFormatterFactory(
                                        new NumberFormatter(amountDisplayFormat),
                                        new NumberFormatter(amountDisplayFormat),
                                        new NumberFormatter(amountEditFormat)));
        amountField.setValue(new Double(amount));
        amountField.setColumns(10);
        amountField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);

        JPanel fieldPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        fieldPane.add(amountField);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

        add(fieldPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        add(new JButton("Hello"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == amountField) {
            amount = ((Number) amountField.getValue()).doubleValue();
            System.out.println("amount = " + amount);
//            amountField.setValue(amount);
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FormatDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new TurkisliraFormatterDemo());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UIManager.put("windows", Boolean.FALSE);
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpFormats() {
        amountDisplayFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("tr", "TR"));
        System.out.println(amountDisplayFormat.format(1200));
        amountDisplayFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        amountEditFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

    }
}
```

Comment: so when when i click on hello focus changes to hello button ?

Comment: Yep, if you refocus the field, it's format will change to the "editor" format again...

Comment: can i use mouse motion event to get my field affect becuase i dont want to put button to my GUI

Comment: can we have invisible implicitly  clicked button ?

Comment: one more question after focus lost and 1200 TL is set ,  is the variable string or big decimal ,  if i want to get the value and store into database ?

Comment: Technically, it's a `Long`, but you should be able to make it what ever you want..

Comment: hello mad programmer how do you make animation like this above ?

Comment: @okrman Ah, trade secret ;) I use a tool called [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/), it's pretty simple, but it's cross platform

Comment: is this free software ? mad programmer i wanna really work with you and improve my self , you are amazing ! thanks